# Converting list to dataframe with serial number of list element

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a list in which each element contains the start and end location of one or more strings from text. Each element may therefore contain several rows or none depending on what is found. I want a dataframe returned which lists the element number and the start/end values as follows:

```
a <- data.frame(start=c(2,3,4,5),
                end=c(5,7,8,9)
)

b <- data.frame(start=numeric(),
                end=numeric())

c <- data.frame(start=c(5,3,4),
                end=c(7,9,8)
)

d <- list(a,b,c)
```

All I am provided with is list d but what I want to get to is dataframe e (which is not in reality provided). I've tried bind_rows, unlisting etc but I am always getting errors. What is the best and most efficient way to achieve this in R? I have provided the result I am seeking as dataframe e below:

```
e <- data.frame(serial_number=c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3),
                    start=c(2,3,4,5,5,3,4),
                    end=c(5,7,8,9,7,9,8)
                    )
```

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(d, .id = "serial_number")` works on your example. How did you try `bind_rows()` and what error did you get?

Comment: (Of course, if you mean what you say that you want the *"most efficient way to achieve this in R"*, then `data.table` should be your first try, not `dplyr`. `data.table::rbindlist(d, idcol = "serial_number")` also works just fine on your example.)

Comment: Thanks for these. Unfortunately list d doesn't yet have the serial_number field, I am trying to create that from the element numbers in the list - that's part of the problem unfortunately

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  that's what `.id = "serial_number"` does in the  `bind_rows` call in my first comment. Or `idcol = "serial_number"` does that in the `rbindlist()` call. Have you tried either of those on your example to see that they work?

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas, thanks for this. Sorry I hadn't twigged that the .id = "serial_number" was creating that field in the column. Just tried this and it is working well thanks. It isn't working on my 'real' data unfortunately and I am now wondering if its because it is a deeply nested list, so will try addressing that and post a new question if I can't resolve that. Thanks very much indeed for your help on this.